# Linking rendered template with Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, handlebars.js

My controller is defined as :

```
broConsoleApp.controller('actionCreateController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$sce', function ($scope, $stateParams, $sce) {
    $scope.html = "";
    var resp = [];
    var params = {};
    /* lot of other things here */ 
    $scope.getHtml = function (type) {
        $scope.html = "";
        $.get(apiHost + "/action/type/defn/" + type).success(function (response) {
            resp = response['RESPONSE']['ActionsParams']['param'];
            console.log(resp);
            if (resp instanceof Array) {
                resp.forEach(function (entry) {
                    $scope.html = $scope.html + $.hbs("/web/templates/actionCreate.hbs", entry);
                });
            }
            else
                $scope.html = $scope.html = $scope.html + $.hbs("/web/templates/actionCreate.hbs", resp);
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
            });
        })
            .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Failed to fetch XML.")
            });
    };
    $scope.add = function(){
        console.log(" entered add ...");
        var $key = $("<input type='text' class='input-small form-control' placeholder='Key'>");
        var $value = $("<input type='text' class='input-small form-control' placeholder='Value'>");
        $('form #'+name).append($key);
        $('form #'+name).append($value);
    };
}]);
```

My get HTML function gets all the HTML and renders it against a JSON . My .hbs file looks like :

```
{{#if_eq type "MAP_VALUED"}}
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 MAP_VALUED" id="{{name}}">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-3">{{label}}</label>

        <form class="col-lg-9 controls form-inline">
            <input type="text" class="input-small form-control" placeholder="Key">
            <input type="text" class="input-small form-control" placeholder="Value">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="add()">+</button>
        </form>
        <br><br>
    </div>
{{/if_eq}}
```

Here I want an onClick action to call the method `$scope.add()` defined in the controller. The ' + ' button adds new key value forms basically.
I am binding this rendered HTML as :

```
<div ng-app="broConsoleApp" ng-controller="actionCreateController">
        <div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
</div>
```

Since the rendered HTML ultimately is defined under broConsoleApp , the ng-cick should work right? Well it is not working. Can someone help me out here. Even if I use a jquery method onClick or something how do I do so without creating a new file. I want it to be in my controller.
Been stuck since morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check working example : https://jsfiddle.net/Shital_D/oyx0fd6e/3/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="broConsoleApp" ng-controller="actionCreateController">
        <div compile="html"></div>
</div>
```

Create directive

```
app.directive('compile', function ($compile) {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
            function (scope) {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function (value) {
                element.html(value);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
       );
   };
});
```

And 
Controller

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.html ='<div><button ng-click="callMe()">clickme</button><div>';
});
```